# Error compiling CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to compile a CUDA kernel but `nvcc` returns me these errors:

```
error: identifier "__shfl_xor" is undefined
error: identifier "__any" is undefined
```

Clearly some header some argument for the compiler is missing... can you help me?
I'm running the CUDA toolkit 5.0 on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: That looks like a gcc incompatibility, are you using the default gcc 4.7? Have you read the Linux release notes?

Comment: Yes I'm using the default gcc and the CUDA toolkit that comes from the repositories

Comment: gcc 4.7 isn't supported by CUDA 5 and neither is Ubuntu 13.04, so why would you expect it to work?

Comment: I thought it was supported, since it's in the official repository. By the way it is the first problem of this kind, all other programs works OK

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling for the correct GPU architecture? Warp vote functions are only supported by devices of compute capability 1.2 and higher. Warp shuffle functions are only supported by devices of compute capability 3.x.

Comment: You also need to include the device_functions.h header file.

Comment: My device is an nVidia GTX 680 which has 3.0 capabilities. Using `-I /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/include/` (the path of device_functions.h) didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue adding `-arch=sm_30` to the command line